# How to set a custom class property into a custom action?

Tags: java, install4j

Today I want to create a custom install action which contains an instance of my custom class as a property. The custom class is instanciated by the *Set Varaible* action of install4j and therefore it is also set to the installation context. Now I want to pass this instance to a custom action. Therefore I've implemented the action with *getter()* and *setter()* methods and created the corresponding *ActionBeanInfo* class. If I put the action inside the IDE into my project configuration I can't set any value to the configuration field for the custom class. Maybe I have to implement some kind of a *PropertyConverter* class for my custom class? I've looked to the sample code but did not find any solution. So how I can get this work?

**AbstractInstallAction** implementation:

```
public class MyCustomAction extends AbstractInstallAction {

  private MyCustomClass instance;

  @Override
  public boolean install(InstallerContext installerContext) throws UserCanceledException {
    ...
    // do some stuff with the MyCustomClass instance
    ...
  }

  public MyCustomClass getMyCustomClass() {
    return instance;
  }

  public void setMyCustomClass(MyCustomClass instance) {
    this.instance= instance;
  }
}
```

**ActionBeanInfo** implementation:

```
public class MyCustomActionBeanInfo extends ActionBeanInfo {

  private static final String PROPERTY_CUSTOM_CLASS = "myCustomClass";

  public MyCustomActionBeanInfo () {
    super("Custom Action.", "This action will do some custom stuff.", null,
            true, false, null, MyCustomAction.class);

    addPropertyDescriptor(create(PROPERTY_CUSTOM_CLASS, getBeanClass(), "Custom class",
            "Sets the custom class to do some custom stuff during installation."));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a property converter that can convert an instance of `MyCustomCass` to a string and optionally a string to an instance `MyCustomClass`.

The interface that you have to implement is `com.install4j.api.beaninfo.PropertyConverter`. Once you have implemented a property converter, you register it in the constructor of your BeanInfo class like this:

```
setPropertyConverters(new PropertyConverter[] {propertyConverters});
```

Comment: Is it recommended to implement the PropertyConverter directly into the ActionBean to get the installation context and read the object from the variable list?

Comment: The bean info works at design time only, there is no installation context at that point. Implementing the PropertyConverted on the action bean is not possible because you do not have the bean instance in the contructor of the bean info.

Comment: Okay, I will try that today. For my custom class it has to be serializable to put it to the installer context variables?

Comment: Yes, otherwise the elevated helper process cannot access them.